# How can I read .sas7bvew files in R?

Tags: r, sas, r-haven

I am looking for a package which can read **.sas7bvew** in **R**. I was trying with haven, but it can only read **.sas7bdat**

I tried the following: (assume **lib2** contains the **data.sas7bvew** file, and I am trying to save it at **lib1**)

```
data lib1.mydata;
set lib2.data;
run;
```

After the above step I can see **data.sas7bdat** is being created at **lib1**. And I can easily read the **.sas7bdat** file with **R**.
Is there any way I can read the **.sas7bvew** file directly in **R**.

Comment: Do you mean sas7bdat? If so, then   library(sas7bdat);

Comment: Please read the description.

Comment: Sure, sure. It just does not compute with me. Quote=" The SAS Data View looks and acts just like a SAS Dataset.
However the Data View contains no data whatsoever. Instead the
Data view contains code." So what are you exactly trying to do? Exporting SAS code to R? See more on http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/sugi27/p069-27.pdf

Comment: Sas7BVew is really a file with a query underneath, not a data table with information.  Do you want the code/query instead?

Comment: @pinegulf I wanted to read the a .sas7bvew file in R. One "trivial" option is to first use a data step in SAS to save the file as .sas7bdat and then read it in R via haven. But I wanted to know if we can do that directly without opening SAS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

There is no data in a view for R or any other non-SAS program to read.